# Reporting Carpal Tunnel in workplace

Tags: human-resources, health

Background: I'm a 25 year old intern by day, I do a lot of word processing, and excel data work and I'm a computer engineering student at night who does a lot of coding

In the past two weeks at my job I've had shooting pains up and down my arm culminating in my middle finger. When I asked my parents about it they said it's probably the onset of carpal tunnel and told me to buy a wrist brace and make an appointment to get it checked out by a doctor. This morning at work someone from HR saw me wearing my wrist brace and told me I have to report it to my manager because it could become a state wide "worker's comp case" (I do not know what this means)

So that I can make a decision whether to report it or keep quiet, what are some pros and cons of reporting it? What are some of the ramifications of keeping it to myself?

Since I'm just an intern I want to make a good impression and work hard and hopefully get a return offer, on the other hand I do want to keep wearing the brace because typing has been a lot easier with it on.

Comment: Depending of which country/state you work, not reporting an injury, that is caused or aggrevated by tyour workplace activity, might be considered violation of labor laws and might affect your chances of getting a return offer adversely.

Comment: VTC as company-specific. HR explicitly told you to report it. **I suggest you listen to them** if you want to keep your job. Follow up with *them* if you want to be sure that it won't affect your chances of being asked to return. There's very little we can say on this.

Comment: You're better off reporting it.  However you see it, its better for everyone in the long run.  Should your injury get worse, you will want this documented now, rather than later when you are trying to get compensated and get turned down.

Comment: One reason to talk to HR is that they may have an ergonomics specialist who can help mitigate the problem--wrong chair height, different keyboard, mouse, how to use keyboard shortcuts, standing desk, whatever. First off, work on switching the mouse to your other hand.

Comment: "*When I asked my parents about it they said it's probably the onset of carpal tunnel and told me to buy a wrist brace and make an appointment to get it checked out by a doctor*" - "My problem was not carpal tunnel syndrome: I avoid that by keeping my wrists pretty straight as I type. There are several kinds of hand pain that can be caused by repetitive stress; don't assume you have the one you heard of." - https://stallman.org/stallman-computing.html

Comment: and  and "Beware of wrist braces. A lot of people try to self-diagnose themselves, and will pick up a cheap set of wrist braces at a drug store and just wear those while typing. Wrist braces can help, but they can also do even more damage. You shouldn't wear them for too long." - https://www.jwz.org/gruntle/wrists.html

Comment: Reporting this is not a big deal most larger companies will help you out by changing your desk set-up and maybe getting you a different keyboard or mouse. Around the office have you seen other employees with odd looking keyboards/chairs or desks? If you have this could mean that they have policies already in place. In my experience this sort of thing is not a big deal. More generally you should watch your posture and start doing exercise either at home or if you can start swimming thats what helped me when i was having similar issues

Answer (score 7):

Go to a doctor and get it documented.  IF this becomes a real medical issue down the line, you'll get hit with the "Pre-existing condition" line.  And you'll be stuck.  Your future employer will **correctly** argue that it didn't happen during your stint with them, and your current employer will then be able to argue that you never said anything when you worked for them.

Go, get examined, and get it documented and tell your doctor **the truth**(tm)

Comment: The unfortunate thing is that even if it's documented (which I agree should happen regardless), his current employer will (also correctly) say that coding is a contributing factor and their worker's comp shouldn't be liable for pay for surgery (which is what usually fixes carpal tunnel)

Comment: Don't worry about the legalities, at this point.  See a doctor as soon as possible.  You may get referred to an occupational therapist who can help.    Take care of yourself, first and foremost.

You may need an altered keyboard or desk.  Professional medical advice is the first step.

Comment: You can't **hand**le the truth! ... :o